# Background REST API call in ios with timer

Tags: swift

I want to know is it possible to call certain APIs with a particular time interval even if app is killed and not in background.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
```

Above code is not working with timer. It get fired only once.

Comment: apple will not let you do that in AppStore app, do you have any reason to do that?

Comment: Yes, we need to make server connection by hitting a api call even if app is closed. It's working perfect in Android but issue is only in iOS. Is there any alternative idea to resolve my issue

Comment: that you just want to do that is not a reason at all, you need a real reason. background fetching should work even if app is killed